# PHP: can't use variable from function in parent function

Tags: php, function

I use two functions. Function 1 ("setImageCopyrightsPost") writes some information into an array ("img_copyrights"), then calls function 2 ("getPostImageThumbnailByID") and after that writes a variable ("img_thumbnail"), that is set in function 2, into the array as well. But the last step is not working.

```
function setImageCopyrightsPost($db_link_backend, $img)
{

    global $img_copyrights;
    global $img_thumbnail;

    $img_copyrights["post-". $img['id']]['title'] = $img['title'];
    $img_copyrights["post-". $img['id']]['copyright'] = $img['copyright'];

    getPostImageThumbnailByID($img['id']);

    $img_copyrights["post-". $img['id']]['url'] = IMG_URL_PATH . $img_thumbnail;

}

function getPostImageThumbnailByID($img_id)
{

    global $img_thumbnail;
    unset($img_thumbnail);

    $sql_get_img_meta_by_id = "SELECT ...'";
    // some SQL-stuff

    if ($num_rows_get_img_meta_by_id == 1 && mysqli_errno($db_link_backend) == 0) {

        $row_get_img_meta_by_id = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_img_meta_by_id);

        // get data from image meta
        unset($preg_matches);
        preg_match("/(\"thumbnail\")(.+?)(\"file\")(.+?)(\")(.+?)(\")(.+?)(\"width\";i:)(.+?)(;)(.+?)(\"height\";i:)(.+?)(;)/m", $row_get_img_meta_by_id['meta_value'], $preg_matches);

        // set name
        $img_thumbnail = $preg_matches[6];

        echo $img_thumbnail;

        return true;

    }
    

}
```

I left out the sql-stuff as I know this is working because the `echo $img_thumbnail` is working - the variable is correctly printed on the page. But when I use `var_dump($img_copyrights)`, just 'title' and 'copyright' are set, 'url' is 'NULL'.

So it seems, that function 1 can't use the variable $img_thumbnail that is set in function 2.

Am I making a mistake or is it normal?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define global variables like that in a function, they must first be defined in global scope.  The proper way would be to return from the second function and assign the return in the first:

```
function setImageCopyrightsPost($db_link_backend, $img)
{
    //remove
    //global $img_thumbnail;

    //code

    $img_thumbnail = getPostImageThumbnailByID($img['id']);  // assign the return

    $img_copyrights["post-". $img['id']]['url'] = IMG_URL_PATH . $img_thumbnail;

}

function getPostImageThumbnailByID($img_id)
{
        //remove
        //global $img_thumbnail;
        //unset($img_thumbnail);

        //code

        $img_thumbnail = $preg_matches[6];

        return $img_thumbnail;  // return the variable

}
```

A hackish way would be to replace all instances of `$img_thumbnail` with `$GLOBALS['img_thumbnail']`, but don't.

Comment: Thank you, your version is working.

But you said, I can't define global variables like that in a function. Is that a real rule or just "better coding"?
Cause I do that in a lot of functions and it works perfectly. For example I set `global $whatever`, return true, false or "error" and can use the `$whatever` on the page where I call the function.

Comment: The only way that would work is if `$whatever` is first defined in global scope (not in a function) and then `global $whatever;` makes it available in the function.  You can't define the variable for the first time in the function and make it global, unless you use the superglobal `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: That's strange, because i can and it's working in every single function i use it - except the example above. But I'm not quite sure if it's because of the global-stuff or for some other reason.